# How to undo the "join" command without pressing control or command Z?

Tags: objects

How can I "un-join" curve objects that were joined with the *Join* command without having to convert them to mesh objects? If this is not possible, why hasn't it been implemented?

Answer (score 2):

You can [separate](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/editing/curve.html#separate) selected splines into new curve objects.

Go into edit mode <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> of the curve object. Select the part which should be separated (linked selection <kbd>L</kbd> is useful here). Press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate.

[image: separate]

Comment: I was looking for a way to separate all joined objects at once but this will do it. Thank you!